# How do I modify this regex to validate URIs with empty parameter value in querystring?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this code to validate URIs in php:

```
preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $uri)
```

However, this won't pass for URIs that end with a equals sign.

e.g. `http://example.com?query=fish&offset=10` returns true, `http://example.com?query=fish&offset=` doesn't.

I can't see why this should be the case from the regex as it allows all characters following the ? sign.

Any tips?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: It doesn't return true, because neither are valid URLs.  You need a `/` after the domain.  Then it will work.  (So the bug is that the first one returns `true`)...

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx isn't working as you anticipate.

Your second group `(.[a-z0-9-]+)*` is capturing EVERYTHING past `http://e`. However, it requires that there are at least 2 characters to work, and since it's greedy, it will capture as much as it possibly can.

Try this instead:

`^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)?(/[-a-z0-9=?&/]*)?$`

If need be, change the last capturing group to include any characters you might need to include in your query string or URI.